# javascript custom converter deserialize json array

Tags: c#, json

I have an object model that includes an array of longs and I'm deserializing a json string that contains an array using a custom javascript converter and the javascript serializer class.

I thought this would work but it doesn't:

```
List<long> TheList = new List<long>;

if (dictionary.ContainsKey("TheArray") && dictionary["TheArray"] != null)
{
    TheList = serializer.ConvertToType<List<long>>(dictionary["TheArray"]); //bug
    TheObject.TheObjectList = (from s in TheList 
                               select Convert.ToInt64(s)).ToList<long>();
}
```

The error is on the line `TheList = serializer.ConvertToType...` and the error message is:

> Cannot convert object of type 'System.String' to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int64]'

I also tried this:

```
var TheStringArray = serializer.ConvertToType<string>(dictionary["TheArray"]);

TheObject.TheObjectList = (from s in TheStringArray.Split(',') 
                           select Convert.ToInt64(s)).ToList<long>();
```

But then I get this error message:

> Type 'System.String' is not supported for deserialization of an array.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Are all the values in the array (string?) valid Int64 values?

Comment: yes, they're all javascript int values. As a precaution, I'm actually also parsing the values to Int64 on the following line.

Comment: Please show us your JSON

Comment: The json is a dictionary that contains an array of number, all classic, nothing fancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array is visible to `JavaScriptConverter` as `ArrayList`, you may approach the deserialization like this:

```
List<long> theArray = null;

if (dictionary.ContainsKey("TheArray") && dictionary["TheArray"] is ArrayList)
{
    theArray = new List<long>();
    ArrayList serializedTheArray = (ArrayList)dictionary["TheArray"];
    foreach (object serializedTheArrayItem in serializedTheArray)
    {
        if (serializedTheArrayItem is Int64)
            theArray.Add((long)serializedTheArrayItem);
    }
}
```

This will do all types checking in case there is somethign unexpected in the JSON. Of course it assumes that `TheArray` property in JSON in fact contains an Array, not inner JSON string which represents Array (the error message might suggest this kind of issue).

Comment: ok, I'm able to get your serializedTheArray to contain the array. Now I'm working on writing the second line with linq like I have it in the question instead of the foreach loop.